# GORM seems to fabricate table names on it's own

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a gorilla/mux site, that I need to use GORM for database handling with.

First, I just wanted to do like a hello world to see if i could access the database.

So have the following code:

```
type user struct {
    user_id  int
    username string
    email    string
    pw_hash  string
}

func gormo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    db, err := gorm.Open(sqlite.Open("test.db"), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }

    var user user
    db.Find(&user)

    fmt.Println(user)

}
```

Now, the database has a table called user, and I just want something returned from it. When this code is run, I get the following command line error:

```
no such table: users
[0.217ms] [rows:0] SELECT * FROM `users`
```

This is weird, nowhere in my code do I have anything called 'users', not im my database either.
Where does this s come from, and why does GORM seem to be putting it there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in your database yet. Well, nothing created by GORM, anyway. You need to [migrate](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html) first. That will create your table. You may do it like this:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&user{})
```

Also, GORM *prefers convention over configuration*, and it [pluralizes table names by default](https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#Conventions). So, once your table is created, its name will be `users`.

Edit: You will probably need to make your struct, along with its fields, externally visible by capitalizing their names.

Comment: I dont see what the migration should have to do with the question, but it seems like the pluralize thing is what I was looking for

Comment: Well, the wording of your question seemed to imply you were having issues with the tables not being created by GORM, but then I got that wrong. Glad I could still help, though.

Comment: Also, if you don't want it to pluralize the table name you can pass a `gorm.Config{NamingStrategy: schema.NamingStrategy{SingularTable: true}}` to `gorm.Open`